# Would this cause a retain cycle if I had this function in an object?

Tags: swift

Let's say I have an object called "PostFactory" that are used by several view controllers. I want to create the UITableViewCells with this factory. If the PostFacotry object was a singleton, would this function

A) Register the cell to the correct tableView(postsView) on the respective viewcontroller, even though I'm only sending the cell back?

B) Would it create a memory leak?

**Note that each delegate is weak b/c each protocol abides by class

```
func createPost(indexPath:NSIndexPath, postView: UITableView, viewCon: UIViewController) -> Posts {
    let Post = postsView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(PostsReuseId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Posts
    Post.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    Post.delegate = viewCon
    Post.fullScreenDelegate = viewCon

    return Post
}
```

Comment: Assuming that method is in the `PostFactory` singleton, you will not have any retain cycles between the `PostFactory` and other objects because `PostFactory` isn't holding references to any of those objects. Is that your question?

Comment: yes to the second part, but what about the first? Will it accomplish what I'm trying to achieve in terms of UITableViewCell creation? I'm trying to gain a better understanding, while refactoring my first app!

Comment: Yes a cell will be dequeued, it's background color and delegate set correctly and be returned. I'm not sure of the advantage of putting it into a singleton instead of a method though